# Android 12 WI-FI Connection

Tags: android, wifi, android-wifi, esp8266wifi, google-pixel

**Phone Model: Google Pixel 4
Os version : Android 12**

We have tried to connect Open wifi of IOT device from System but it showing obtaining IP address and never changed state of that one.
Before **Android 12** it connects successfully.

Things tried to sort out

1.Forgot Device and reconnect devices.

2 Reboot device.

3.Factory Reset device.

4 Reset Network Settings.

Is there any specific reason or any problem in Android 12?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, on Android 12 they introduced Concurrent Peer-to-Peer + Internet Connection.
https://developer.android.com/about/versions/12/behavior-changes-12#concurrent-connections

You can use their new APIs to get the IoT device's connection.
However I'm having a problem in my app when I try to serve a firmware upgrade using a local HTTP server on Android. NanoHTTPd seems to be using the primary Wi-Fi connection, even though the app's process is bonded to the secondary Wi-Fi.
If you find anything on that, please let me know too haha